# Add arrays of value in object propertie javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read all the values of an attribute my page an get, for each attribute (some attribute can has multiple value separate by comma) the div id
This is my html page:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-att]');

let obj = {};

elements.forEach(function(element) {
  let v = element.getAttribute('data-att');
  let id = element.id;
  comma = v.includes(",");
  if (comma) {
    s = v.split(",");
    s.forEach(function(single) {
      obj[single] = {
        id: id
      };
    });
  } else {
    obj[v] = {
      id: id
    };
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="due" data-att="foo"></div>
  <div id="uno" data-att="foo"></div>
  <div id="tre" data-att="foo,bar"></div>
  <div id="quattro" data-att="brum"></div>
  <div id="cinque" data-att="foo,brum"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

## What's the problem?

At the moment i needed to assign the attrbute id using `obj[single] = {id: id};` cause i tried to make a `obj[single].push(id);` but I get error

Anyone can hel me to reach this resoult:

```
  {
  "foo": {
     ['due','uno','tre','cinque']
  },
  "bar": {
    ['tre']
  },
  "brum": {
    ['cinque']
  }
}
```

Comment: if( obj[single] === undefined ) obj[single] = [ id ] ; else obj[single].push( id ) ;

Comment: Why does your code have `{id: id}`? Your desired result doesn't have any object with an `id` property.

Comment: it was the only way to make it work, in wrong mode but without error

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-att]');
let obj = {};

elements.forEach(el => {
  const keys = el.dataset.att.split(',');
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(obj[key] === undefined){
      obj[key] = [];
    }
    obj[key].push(el.id)
  })
})

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id="due" data-att="foo"></div>
    <div id="uno" data-att="foo"></div>
    <div id="tre" data-att="foo,bar"></div>
    <div id="quattro" data-att="brum"></div>
    <div id="cinque" data-att="foo,brum"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is not the same you posted, i think you made a mistake there, or was it me? :)

Comment: Yes sorry I write the result by hands your is exactly

Answer (score 0):

Check if the property already exists. If it does, push onto the array, otherwise create the array.

There's no need for `if (comma)`. Splitting a string with no comma will return an array with a single element, you can loop over this with `forEach()`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-att]');

let obj = {};

elements.forEach(function(element) {
  let v = element.getAttribute('data-att');
  let id = element.id;
  s = v.split(",");
  s.forEach(function(single) {
    if (obj[single]) {
      obj[single].push(id);
    } else {
      obj[single] = [id];
    }
  });
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="due" data-att="foo"></div>
  <div id="uno" data-att="foo"></div>
  <div id="tre" data-att="foo,bar"></div>
  <div id="quattro" data-att="brum"></div>
  <div id="cinque" data-att="foo,brum"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I add if comma, cause In the first test running without that I wasn't seeing single attribute result, and I didn't investigate more